# Getting column names from a table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, sysobjects

I am trying to get column names for a Given table. So I wrote a query like this:

```
  SELECT   sc.Name
   FROM     Asdim.dbo.sysobjects so
            INNER JOIN Asdim.dbo.syscolumns sc ON so.id = sc.id
            INNER JOIN Asdim.dbo.systypes st ON sc.xtype = st.xusertype
   WHERE    so.Name = 'Admin'
```

The problem is that I have two tables with name 'Admin' but they have different schemas. So when I run this query:

```
SELECT * FROM Asdim.dbo.sysobjects
WHERE name LIKE 'Admin'
```

I get two records since the table names are same. Is there a way that I caould filter out based on the schema name too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Using the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186778.aspx) tables will be easier and more portable:

```
SELECT c.column_name
  FROM information_schema.columns c
 WHERE c.table_name = 'Admin' and c.table_schema = 'SCHEMA'
```

[More info on `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188348.aspx).